# Nginx not serving updatd files

Tags: caching, nginx

On some clients updates are not getting reflected.

### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    expires off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
# SSL Settings
        ##
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
# Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
# Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

    ##
# nginx-naxsi config
    ##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
# nginx-passenger config
    ##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

#passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
# Virtual Host Configs
    ##


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 }


 #mail {
 #  # See sample authentication script at:
 #  # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
 #
 #  # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
 #  # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
 #  # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
 #
 #  server {
 #      listen     localhost:110;
 #      protocol   pop3;
 #      proxy      on;
 #  }
 #
 #  server {
 #      listen     localhost:143;
 #      protocol   imap;
 #      proxy      on;
 #  }
 #}
```

### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
        # http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
        # http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
        #
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/app.morph.ai/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/app.morph.ai/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
            server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    expires off;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
#error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
#location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
                #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
#location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

### Call headers

Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:615972
Content-Type:application/x-javascript
Date:Thu, 10 Nov 2016 15:56:52 GMT
ETag:"582496c2-96624"
Last-Modified:Thu, 10 Nov 2016 15:48:18 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:app.morph.ai
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
```

### Other Details

Trying to get the file from curl always gives the updated file. The problem is only with browsers.

Also on client where the new file is getting reflected I am getting following in access logs :

`47.31.13.38 - - [10/Nov/2016:15:57:33 +0000] "GET /main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 615972 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"`

and on the client where I the changes are not getting reflected I am getting following access logs:

`150.242.62.25 - - [10/Nov/2016:16:13:03 +0000] "GET /main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 67389 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"`.

The original file size is `615972` but on second host the size of content delivered is `67389`.

Comment: Strange... Have you tried clearing browser cache (or force-reload Ctrl + F5) on both clients and then retrying? Also, your app is serving your static content with ETags, this might be another issue even with `no-cache` headers

Comment: Yes I did delete the browser cache. Also in chrome I try reloading with disabling the cache. Let me check for ETags

Comment: Any feedback yet?

Comment: Was just doing that. Now I am unable to find any client where this is happening. But from access logs I can see the the call returned 200. If ETag caching is happening then server should have returned 304. Independent of that I also turned off ETag.

Comment: True, if ETags were used and serving old data, not modified would be the response. When you say you can't find a client where it's happening, do you mean it's now consistent across all clients? Also, are you getting the expected behaviour or is it still not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: Right on on all my testing client I am getting expected behaviour. But yesterday only on one client I was getting wrong behaviour.